# How to use PHP FORM with Facebook PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, forms, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to make a Facebook APP, that prints some questions (answers in radio buttons) and than after submisson it gives the result. The permission request and user login works... but i can't figure out how to submit the FORM and get the variables...

I started with this tutorial: [quiz tutorial](http://onlytipsandtricks.com/facebook/creating-facebook-quiz-application-without-database-2/)

the index.php of this quiz APP is this:

```
<?php include_once "config.php";


$xmlFile = "questions.xml";


$data = implode("", file($xmlFile)); $parser = xml_parser_create(); xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0); xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1); xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $data, $values, $tags); xml_parser_free($parser);

$questionNo = 0; foreach ($values as $key=>$val) {  // save value to "questions" array if this is a TEXT tag    if ($val[tag] == "TEXT") {      $questions[$questionNo]['text'] = $val[value];  }

    // save value to "questions" array if this is a CHOICES tag     if ($val[tag] == "CHOICES") {       $questions[$questionNo]['choices'] = $val[value];   }

    // save value to "questions" array if this is an ANSWER tag     if ($val[tag] == "ANSWER") {        $questions[$questionNo]['answer'] = $val[value];

        // increment question counter variable      $questionNo++;  } }

import_request_variables("p", "post_");



if (!isset($post_answers)) {    echo "<b>" . $questions[0]['text'] . "</b>\n";  echo "<form action=\"$PHP_SELF\" method=\"post\">\n";

    // split choices into "choices" array   $choices = explode(", ", $questions[0]['choices']);

    // print text field if there are no choices     if (count($choices) == 1) {         echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"answers[0]\" size=10>\n";     }

    // print radio fields if there are multiple choices     else {      // print a radio button for each choice         for ($i = 0; $i < count($choices); $i++) {          echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"answers[0]\" value=\"" . $choices[$i] . "\"> " . $choices[$i] . "<br>\n";        }   }

    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Next Question\">\n";   echo "</form>\n"; }




elseif (count($questions) > count($post_answers)) {         $nextQuestion = count($post_answers);

        echo "<b>" . $questions[$nextQuestion]['text'] . "</b>\n";  echo "<form action=\"$PHP_SELF\" method=\"post\">\n";

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($post_answers); $i++) {         echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"answers[$i]\" value=\"$post_answers[$i]\">\n";  }

        $choices = explode(", ", $questions[$nextQuestion]['choices']);

        if (count($choices) == 1) {         echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"answers[$nextQuestion]\" size=10>\n";     }

        else {      // print a radio button for each choice         for ($i = 0; $i < count($choices); $i++) {          echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"answers[$nextQuestion]\" value=\"" . $choices[$i] . "\">" . $choices[$i] . "<br>\n";         }   }

    // print appropriate button label   if (count($questions) == count($post_answers) + 1) {        echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Calculate Score\">\n";     }   else {      echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Next Question\">\n";   }

    echo "</form>\n"; }




else {  // get number of questions  $noQuestions = count($questions);

    // get number of correct answers    for ($i = 0; $i < $noQuestions; $i++) {         // increment "noCorrectAnswers" variable if user has correct answer         if ($questions[$i]['answer'] == $post_answers[$i]) {            $noCorrectAnswers++;        }   }

    // calculate score  $score = ($noCorrectAnswers / $noQuestions) * 100;

    // round score to nearest whole precentage point    $score = round($score);

    // print score  echo "<h2>$score%</h2>\n";

    if ($noCorrectAnswers == 0) {       echo "<p>You answered no questions correctly.  <a href=" . $PHP_SELF . ">Try again.</a></p>";   }

    if ($noCorrectAnswers == 1) {       echo "<p>You answered 1 out of $noQuestions questions correctly.  <a href=" . $PHP_SELF . ">Try again.</a></p>";    }

    if ($noCorrectAnswers > 1 && $noCorrectAnswers < $noQuestions) {        echo "<p>You answered $noCorrectAnswers out of $noQuestions questions correctly.  <a href=" . $PHP_SELF . ">Try again.</a></p>";    }

    if ($noCorrectAnswers == $noQuestions) {        echo "<p>You answered all questions correctly!</p>";    } }



?>
```

it works fine (but had to remove the $session). The problem is, if i put this into my index.php frame, it stops working... i think it must be some variable loss thing...

...

```
        try {
                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me'); 

                $scope = 'publish_stream,user_photos'; 
                $scope_params = explode(',',$scope);

                $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions"); 

                    if( array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) &&  array_key_exists('user_photos', $permissions['data'][0])) {

                        // here are the above index.php codes

                    } else {
                        $user = null;
                    }


    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }
    }

if ($user) {
// logged in user
} else {
    // not logged in or not authenticated
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">top.location.href = "'.$loginUrl .'";</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ready template application that can do this for you , one of them is [Zoomerang](http://www.zoomerang.com/facebook-surveys/)